# Drupal 7: Omega theme - issue setting an image as banner

Tags: css, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I have created a sub-theme from Omega and I am trying to set an image which is `960x122` as a banner image for the sub-theme. I edited the my-subtheme-omegatheme-alpha-default.css file as following -

```
.branding-data {
background: white no-repeat url(../graphics/banner.jpg);
}
```

When I added the above, the site shows only a portion of the banner. The banner image got stripped from top and bottom. Also, there is space on the right side of the banner image. I am newbie to Drupal. Please help me.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Drupal usage, belongs to http://drupal.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you are using CSS the use width : 100%; to selector.should help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a css problem.
I don't know Drupal very well but you can try to set a 'height' attribute in your css and make some test such as following example

```
.branding-data {
    background: white no-repeat url(../graphics/banner.jpg);
    width: 100%;
    /* use your banner heigth size */
    heigth: 300px; 
}
```